# C# crystal report parameter missing error

Tags: c#

i have tried to load the report make use of parameter selection. i have done the all neccesssary things manually to the form and report also. Bt i did'nt get the value on the report. report would shown as blank. This is what the code i have written in form behind.

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("MR1.rpt"));
//reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "SureshDasari", "MySampleDB");
reportdocument.SetParameterValue("Material_Code", txtMC.Text);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
    }
}
```

Please correct me

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the Logon parameters. Have you set "Enable Database Logon Prompting" to true?

And try Loading full path load:

```
reportDocument.Load(@"FullPathOfYourReport");
```